# (Python) Idk what to do

Tags: python

So I was learning how to make a tic tac toe game from a website and when I finished, I couldn't play it because I keep getting the same error, I checked my work and every thing was fine, here's the code

```
import random
from time import sleep
print "To play this game, you use your 1-9 keys"
print "This is layout of each number representing a square"
print "7|8|9"
print "4|5|6"
print "1|2|3"
print " "
def drawboard(board): #Draws the board
    print "Board"
    print '' + board[7] + '|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9]
    print '' + board[4] + '|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6]
    print '' + board[1] + '|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3]

def inputplayerletter(): #Asks player if they want to be X or O
    letter = ''
    while not letter == 'X' or letter == 'O':
        print "Do you want to be X or O?"
        letter = raw_input(" ").upper()
    if letter == 'X':
        return ['X', 'O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']

def whogoesfirst(): #This determines who goes first
    if random.randint(0,1) == '0':
        return 'computer'
    else:
        return 'player'

def playagain(): #Asks player if it wants to play again
    print "Do you want to play again?(Y/N)"
    return raw_input("").lower().startswith('y')

def makemove(board, letter, move): #When someone makes a move we execute this function
    board[move] = letter

def winner(bo,le): #Determines whose the winner
    return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or
    (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or
    (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or
    (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or
    (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)


def getboardcopy(board): #Creates a copy of the board for the computer AI
    dupeboard = []
    for i in dupeboard:
        dupeboard.append(i)
    return dupeboard

def isspacefree(board, move): #Checks if space is free.
    return board[move] == ''

def playermove(board): #Where the player inputs his/her move
    move = ''
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isspacefree(board, int(move)):
        print "your move (Pick from 1-9)"
        move = raw_input("")
    return int(move)

def choosemovefromlist(board, movelist): #chooses possible moves from list
    possiblemoves = []
    for i in moveslist:
        if isspacefree(board, i):
            possiblemoves.append(i)
    if len(possiblemoves) != 0:
        return random.choice(possiblemove)
    else:
        return None

def computerai(board, computerletter): #Computer AI
    if computerletter == 'X':
        playerletter = 'O'
    else:
        playerletter = 'X'

    for i in range(1,10):
        dupe = getboardcopy(board)
        if isspacefree(copy, i):
            makemove(board, computerletter, i)
            if winner(copy, computerletter):
                return i
    for i in range(1,10):
        dupe = getboardcp[y(board)
        if isspacefree(copy, i):
            makemove(board, playerletter, i)
            if winner(copy, playerletter):
                return i
    move = choosemovefromlist(board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
    if move != None:
        return move
    if isspacefree(board, 5):
        return 5
    return choosemovefromlist(board[2,4,6,8])

def isboardfull(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if isspacefree(board, i):
            return False
    return True

print "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"

while True:
    theboard = [''] * 10
    print "Flipping the coin..."
    sleep(2)
    turn = whogoesfirst()
    print "The " + turn + " goes first."
    gameinprogress = True
    while gameinprogress:
        if turn == 'player':
            drawboard(theboard)
            move = getplayermove(theboard)
            makemove = (theboard, playerletter, move)
            if winner(theboard, playerletter):
                drawboard(theboard)
                print "The player wins the game! Congratulations!"
                gameinprogress = False
            else:
                if isboardfull(theboard):
                    drawboard(theboard)
                    print "Tie game! No one wins!"
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'computer'
        else:
            move = computerai(theboard, computerletter)
            makemove(theboard, computerletter, move)
            if winner(theboard, computerletter):
                drawboard(theboard)
                print "The computer has beaten the player!"
                break
            else:
                turn = 'player'
    if not playagain():
        break
```

I keep getting an error here:

```
def getboardcopy(board): #Creates a copy of the board for the computer AI
    dupeboard = []
    for i in dupeboard:
        dupeboard.append(i)
    return dupeboard

def isspacefree(board, move): #Checks if space is free.
    return board[move] == ''

def playermove(board): #Where the player inputs his/her move
    move = ''
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isspacefree(board, int(move)):
        print "your move (Pick from 1-9)"
        move = raw_input("")
    return int(move)

def choosemovefromlist(board, movelist): #chooses possible moves from list
    possiblemoves = []
    for i in moveslist:
        if isspacefree(board, i):
            possiblemoves.append(i)
    if len(possiblemoves) != 0:
        return random.choice(possiblemove)
    else:
        return None

def computerai(board, computerletter): #Computer AI
    if computerletter == 'X':
        playerletter = 'O'
    else:
        playerletter = 'X'

    for i in range(1,10):
        dupe = getboardcopy(board)
        if isspacefree(copy, i):
            makemove(board, computerletter, i)
            if winner(copy, computerletter):
                return i
    for i in range(1,10):
        dupe = getboardcp[y(board)
        if isspacefree(copy, i):
            makemove(board, playerletter, i)
            if winner(copy, playerletter):
                return i
    move = choosemovefromlist(board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
    if move != None:
        return move
    if isspacefree(board, 5):
        return 5
    return choosemovefromlist(board[2,4,6,8])

def isboardfull(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if isspacefree(board, i):
            return False
    return True

print "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"
```

even if I remove a defined function here, another error appears.

So when I ran the code normally, this is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 49
    def getboardcopy(board): #Creates a copy of the board for the computer AI
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So when I remove that defined function from my code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 50
    def isspacefree(board, move): #Checks if space is free.
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even if I remove that function too, the same error happens to the function after this function, and then if I remove every single function starting from def getboardcopy, I get an error at my print statement. Then when I remove that I get another error from the while loop. I'm using Python 2.7.2

Comment: You forgot a closing parenthesis in your `winner` function.  Voting to close as typo.

Comment: In the future, try to follow the rules at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting a question -- code included should be cut down to the shortest possible amount that creates the same error when someone else runs it. Often, the effort to isolate a problem that way will be enough that you solve it yourself.

Comment: Suggestion:  Code less and test more.  Stop frequently to make sure everything still works.  If you had tested this after adding every function, a new syntax error would have been easy to find, because there would have been only a dozen or so new lines for it to hide in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a ton of syntax errors and calls to non-existing variables. The program was also missing a call to the inputplayerletter() in the main while loop. It will run now, but you will need to fix all the logic issues that still exist.

```
import random
    from time import sleep
    print "To play this game, you use your 1-9 keys"
    print "This is layout of each number representing a square"
    print "7|8|9"
    print "4|5|6"
    print "1|2|3"
    print " "

def drawboard(board): #Draws the board
    print "Board"
    print ''.join(board[7]) + '|'.join(board[8]) + '|'.join(board[9])
    print ''.join(board[4]) + '|'.join(board[5]) + '|'.join(board[6])
    print ''.join(board[1]) + '|'.join(board[2]) + '|'.join(board[3])

def inputplayerletter(): #Asks player if they want to be X or O
    letter = ''
    while not letter == 'X' or letter == 'O':
        print "Do you want to be X or O?"
        letter = raw_input(" ").upper()
    if letter == 'X':
        return ['X', 'O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']

def whogoesfirst(): #This determines who goes first
    if random.randint(0,1) == '0':
        return 'computer'
    else:
        return 'player'

def playagain(): #Asks player if it wants to play again
    print "Do you want to play again?(Y/N)"
    return raw_input("").lower().startswith('y')

def makemove(board, letter, move): #When someone makes a move we execute this                 function
    board[move] = letter

def winner(bo,le): #Determines whose the winner
    return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or
    (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or
    (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or
    (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or
    (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or
    (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)) #missing )

def getboardcopy(board): #Creates a copy of the board for the computer AI
    dupeboard = []
    for i in dupeboard:
        dupeboard.append(i)
    return dupeboard

def isspacefree(board, move): #Checks if space is free.
    return board[move] == ''

def playermove(board): #Where the player inputs his/her move
    move = ''
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isspacefree(board,     int(move)):
    print "your move (Pick from 1-9)"
    move = raw_input("")
    return int(move)

def choosemovefromlist(board, movelist): #chooses possible moves from list
    possiblemoves = []
    for i in moveslist:
        if isspacefree(board, i):
            possiblemoves.append(i)
    if len(possiblemoves) != 0:
        return random.choice(possiblemove)
    else:
        return None


def computerai(board, computerletter): #Computer AI
    if computerletter == 'X':
        playerletter = 'O'
    else:
        playerletter = 'X'
    for i in range(1,10):
        dupe = getboardcopy(board)
        if isspacefree(board, i):
            makemove(board, computerletter, i)
            if winner(board, computerletter):
                return i
    for i in range(1,10):
        dupe = getboardcp[y(board)]  # missing ]
        if isspacefree(copy, i):
            makemove(board, playerletter, i)
            if winner(copy, playerletter):
                return i
    move = choosemovefromlist(board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
    if move != None:
        return move
    if isspacefree(board, 5):
        return 5
    return choosemovefromlist(board[2,4,6,8])

def isboardfull(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if isspacefree(board, i):
            return False
    return True

print "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"

while True:
    theboard = [''] * 10
    print "Flipping the coin..."
    sleep(2)
    turn = whogoesfirst()
    print "The " + turn + " goes first."
    playerletter = inputplayerletter()
    if playerletter == 'X':
        computerletter = 'O'
    else:
        computerletter = 'X'
    gameinprogress = True
    while gameinprogress:
        if turn == 'player':
            drawboard(theboard)
            move = playermove(theboard) #remove get from getplayermove
            makemove(theboard, playerletter, move)
            if winner(theboard, playerletter):
                drawboard(theboard)
                print "The player wins the game! Congratulations!"
                gameinprogress = False
            else:
                if isboardfull(theboard):
                    drawboard(theboard)
                    print "Tie game! No one wins!"
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'computer'
        else:
            move = computerai(theboard, computerletter)
            makemove(theboard, computerletter, move)
            if winner(theboard, computerletter):
                drawboard(theboard)
                print "The computer has beaten the player!"
                break
            else:
                turn = 'player'
    if not playagain():
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is closed as it should be this is a good learning opportunity.  When you get that type of cascading error it usually means something is unbalanced above the error message.

Another way you should have been able to tell is by the fact that every time you hit the enter key your cursor did not end up where you expected it to end up.

So the error as pointed out is that

```
def winner(bo,le): #Determines whose the winner
    return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or
           (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or
           (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or
           (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or
           (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or
           (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or
           (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or
           (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)) <- this was missing
```